# android cardview onclick to display more details

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, cardview

I'm working on an android rest client application, and i, now can retreive data from a local server but i'm willing to display more data when a cardview from my recycler view is clicked. So if anyone has an idea on how to do it, or a tutorial please share it.

Answer (score 0):

hmmm i think this is will help you when click into card view

```
   holder.lnrLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            intent.putExtra("movie_year",getDataAdapter1.getMovie_year()) ;
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```